# URL Redirection without changing url in address bar

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to load contents of `http://www.example.com/store/index` whenever someone visits `http://www.example.com/` without changing the URL. I tried the following URL and it doesn't work. Please help. Am I missing something very basic?

`RewriteRule / /store/index [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+store/index[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /store/index [L]
```

- You need to match `^/?$` to make sure you're only rewriting home page
- You must not use `R` flag to avoid URL changing in browser

Comment: That works like a charm. If we want to change url to www.example.com if anyone hits /store/index directly, does it cause infinite redirect? Can you suggest a rule?

Comment: Cool. \s/ is it a delimiter?

Comment: `\s` just matches a whitespace in regex

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+store/index[?\s/] [NC]` this line is to make sure the request url is /store/index and nothing else? You seem to be a regex god.

Comment: Yes we are using `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+store/index[?\s/] [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]`

This part doesn't seem to work for some reason. It just stays as is instead of redirecting to /

Comment: I just tested it again and it worked. Do you other rules OR another .htaccess in `/store/` folder?

Comment: Yes, there is a .htaccess file inside `/store/`, Is that taking over?

Comment: Yes it is taking over. Place this 1st 301 rule inside `/store/` as first rule.